# What companies across the world are manufacturing 35mm film, and where (as of August 2018)?

Tags: film, manufacturing

Although there are numerous film brands available in shops and online, I'm interested in knowing who is manufacturing them, and where their factories are.

I've limited the question to 35mm film, because I'm most interested in general-purpose film rather than specialist film for niche markets.

Comment: While I'm still a film user and mildly interested myself, I'm wondering why you want to know. Why is this information useful to anyone, other than to satisfy curiosity?

Comment: Additionally, I'm not sure that 120 film is any more "niche" than 135 film.

Comment: I feel like this question would be more satisfying if you listed out the emulsions you are directly curious about. There's nothing really all that different about 35, 120, 4x5, etc. (other than size...dur) if they're using the same emulsion.

Comment: @osullic Why *should* the information be useful to anyone?

Comment: @Hueco I imagined there would be facilities producing film for scientific purposes for example. As for emulsions - I simply don't know enough to list them!

Comment: Well, there's not that many and I'd imagine the facility would produce both consumer and scientific in the same place - though I'm not certain on that. Are you interested in color neg, color slide, and b&w or just a subset?

Comment: @osullic I'd imagine that Daniele needs to know in order to stage some corporate espionage to obtain the formula for PanF+ so that we can make it in our bathtubs when it goes the way of Polaroid.

Comment: @DanieleProcida Why should it be useful? See [the site help](https://photo.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask), which notes: "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face." So, it's not that non-useful questions aren't sometimes interesting. They're juts really not in scope.

Comment: @mattdm Fair enough. Knowing who makes what film helps understand what different brands actually amount to (cf. the continued speculation about who makes what for whom and whether brand X really is what it used to be, or is now simply formulation Y repackaged). And knowing *where* can help understand whether say a Chinese film is actually an interesting new film you've never seen before, or some boring old thing under a different name.

Answer (score 4):

The biggest issue in film manufacture is the cost of keeping a coating line up and running. The capital expenditure requires high volume of coated film to be economical. Creating emulsion is comparatively easy (the big problems were sorted out long ago) and the rest is "just" marketing.

It is therefore common for film "manufacturers" to rent lines from other producers (which makes sense to them as well, as the lines date from earlier times and have capacity to spare, and the big enemy is digital).

As far as I know there are three major film coating lines still going in Europe:

- [Ilford](https://www.ilfordphoto.com/) in the UK
- [Inoviscoat](http://www.inoviscoat.de/) in Germany (former AGFA line, does not have own brand)
- [Foma](http://www.foma.cz/en/homepage) in the Czech Republic

I am unsure whether to consider [Ferrania](http://www.filmferrania.it/) as a film manufacturer or a performer of concept art. But they seem to have a line too.

Overseas Kodak has a line and Fuji have a line.

In Russia there is [Tasma](http://www.tasma.ru/en/) and in Ukraine [Astrum](http://www.astrum-ltd.com) but it is hard to verify if they are still in business of making new film, or just selling existing stock.

There is rumored to be a line running in China. Hindustani films in India are likely defunct by now.

Comment: Can you clarify in that case: do the formulation owners in effect ship a truckload of chemicals to a plant and say: *coat this onto some plastic for us*? (In which case knowing which companies are shipping which emulsions to which plants would actually be more useful.)

Comment: It doesn't quite work like that. There is very little new development of emulsions - what there is is about replacing banned chemicals, not producing a different outcome. Owning a recipe does not give you much leverage. What matters is marketing and distribution + scale in production. Things like getting hold of silver and plastic backing in cost effective matter. By the way obtaining the "some plastic" you mention is getting more and more difficult, as plastic industry evolves, introducing new materials and abandoning old ones, while film manufacturing tries hard to remain in the nineties.